# MSSQL copy a row and save new id

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I have one problem. I'm trying to do trigger where I copy a row (table with identity (1,1) and update this duplicate one.

And what I did is copy the row, and I don't know how I can get the new ID?

```
CREATE TABLE Client
(
nrCl int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
name nchar(50) not null,
lastName nchar(50) not null,
phone int not null
)
```

This is sample, and I have a lot of rows, so I cannot check this new ID all the time

```
CREATE TRIGGER modKlienta 
ON  Klient
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
declare @nrCl int
SET @nrCl = (select nrCl from inserted)
INSERT INTO Client (name, lastName, phone)
SELECT name, lastName, phone
FROM Client
WHERE nrCl = @nrCl
```

And now I don't know, how I can get the new row's ID to update this row.

Comment: Use this: declare @newId int = Scope_identity() just after the insert

Comment: The question does not seem clear to me. You should be aware that a trigger does not operate on a single ROW but on a data volume. If you want to duplicate the new data use *inserted* if you want to dulpicate the 'old' data use *deleted*. If you need a bunch of new id's take a look on [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Comment: I know, my trigger has more abilities, but this only a part of smt bigger, and my code is much more complicated, this is a sample.